# Qt moving a QWidget without triggering the moveEvent method?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to set a widget to remain fixed at the location where it is created initially and never move. I am doing so by setting its position to its old position in an overridden `moveEvent` method. The problem is that the only way to move it is to...call `move`, which triggers another `moveEvent`, entering an infinite loop. Is there a way to set the position directly and bypass any events?

Comment: The bigger question is: if you want the widget to stay put, why are you letting "something" move it? Perhaps the problem is with whatever is moving the widget? Or is it a top-level widget, i.e. a window?

Answer (score 1):

```
bool m_firstTimeMove; // class member for QMyWidget

QMyWidget::QMyWidget(QObject* parent) : QWidget(parent),
   m_firstTimeMove(true)
{
}

void QMyWidget::moveEvent(QMoveEvent* event)
{
   if (m_firstTimeMove)
   {
      onlyForFirstTimeMove();   // do one time move action
      m_firstTimeMove = false;
   }
   event->accept();
}
```

Comment: Won't this just move it only the first time? I want to move it every time back to its old coordinates so it never moves away from them again.

Comment: edit: installEventFilter looks promising to doing what I want

Comment: Maybe you can prevent moving by     setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::Tool); in constructor of widget.

Comment: the event filter seems to do what I want, however QMoveEvent doesn't seem to have a type of QEvent::Move?

Comment: QEvent::Move exists         Move = 13,                              // move widget